# Ubuntu 13.10 Press S To Skip Mount Or M For Manual Recovery corrupted fstab can't modify

Tags: boot, 13.10, mount, fstab

I recently made changes to my fstab file and, upon reboot, noticed I had an error in it. I get the typical mount error on boot. I went to try and modify it by entering the read-only mode but then, since it's read only, I can't access it. Is there a way around this or some way to delete the file so I can use the backup (which I'm pretty sure works)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remount the filesystem read/write, either using the option on the menu, or by running `mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: option in which menu? the booting menu?

Comment: @ZekeDroid, the recovery menu.  The one that lets you choose to fsck, remount rw, drop to a root shell, or boot normally.